# How to get unique file name on every http request in php

Tags: php

I have to create new file on every http request and I want file name should be unique so that no file overwrite other files

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create function to generate an unique value. here is the code for that function.

```
function gen_uuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
}
```

Now call the above function for unique name.
suppose your file extension should be `.txt`. then-

```
$ext = '.txt';
$fileName = gen_uuid().$ext;
```

that will gives you an unique name every time.
you can also use the same function for generating `UUID`.